# Why were Luffy, Zoro, and Usopp surprised when they saw the Dragon from Punk Hazard?

Tags: one-piece

I wonder why Luffy, Zoro, and Usopp (and also Robin) were surprised when they saw the [Dragon from Punk Hazard](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Species/Pirate_Alliance_Saga#Dragon) while the three of them have already seen [Ryu](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ryu), the Dragon that they met on Warship Island?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Their surprise stems from the fact that the Warship Island Arc is a filler arc. As [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Warship_Island_Arc) says:

> It is the first story arc of the series not to be based on any content from the manga by Eiichiro Oda, making it the first filler arc.

Another reason might be the fact that they had [encountered a dragon](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sandora_Lizard#Sandora_Lizard) (if you count it as one) only once before, and didn't expect to meet one on Punk Hazard.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, Zorro also said something like "there's no such thing like that in this world." isn't it?

Comment: When? I don't remember hearing that dialogue. Here's the scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glSsQm9riWI. Can you point out where? Also, they were mainly surprised because the dragon was apparently talking.

Comment: oh, I think it's just me that have really bad memories xD thank you for all you information @AshishGupta

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score -1):

Because it's a filler arc.

In Canon story, they meet dragon for the first time in Punk Hazard. Having said that, it's a mythical creature which never existed in Pirate era, but it was an artificial one created by Genius Vegapunk.